# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el resultado de llamar a una función repetidas veces, en un array numpy?

Tags: python

Mi intención es generar una matriz de matrices numpy con el resultado de haber llamado a una función un número de veces.

Logro que se cree esta matriz, pero en cada uno de sus campos me guarda el resultado de aquel array generado en la última iteración de llamada a la función; y no logro que guarde en cada campo el resultado de cada una de las llamadas a la función, tal y como necesito.

Quisiera saber qué es lo que me falta o lo que no estoy haciendo correctamente?
Gracias.

El código de esta parte es el siguiente:

```
def upd( frame, dm ): 
    dm[:,:]=0.              
    t1 = frame
    t0 = frame - timedelta(minutes=30) 
  
    for i in range(len(P)): 
        if t0 <= T[i] <= t1:
            w = 2*convert( P[i,0], x1.min(), x1.max(), len(x1) )
            h = 2*convert( P[i,1], y1.min(), y1.max(), len(y1) )
            dm[ h,   w   ] += 1
            dm[ h+1, w   ] += 1
            dm[ h,   w+1 ] += 1
            dm[ h+1, w+1 ] += 1
    dm[0,0]=dm[0,-1]=dm[-1,0]=dm[-1,-1]=10      

density_map = numpy.zeros( [ len(Y)+2, len(X)+2 ] )

rango_fechas=list() 
t = datetime( T[0].year, T[0].month, T[0].day, T[0].hour, T[0].minute - (T[0].minute % 10) ) 

while t < T[-1]:
    t += timedelta(minutes=10) 
    rango_fechas.append(t) 

im_den=list()
for pdm in range(len(rango_fechas)):
    upd(rango_fechas[pdm],density_map)
    im_den.append(density_map)
imagenes = numpy.array(im_den)
```

Comment: todo el código que muestras es de la función **upd**? podrías revisar la indentación de tu código?

Comment: Gracias por revisar, el código que muestro aquí es solo es el que se requiere para analizar el error, es decir todo me funciona bien hasta que trato de guardar en una lista el resultado de llamar a la función repetidas veces con el ciclo for. Corregí un error de indentación al copiar, pero no hay error en original. El problema es que logro crear una matriz con el tamaño del resultado de cada llamada a la función (iteración con for), pero en cada posición me guarda el resultado de la última llamada y necesito que en cada posición me guarde el resultado de cada llamada a la función. Gracias.

Comment: vale, ya que corregiste la indentación, ahora debes modificar el código para que sea el [mínimo codigo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y podamos analizar tu problema. Por ejemplo, en tu código están las variables (X, Y, P, T) entre otras, que no sabemos por este código, que forma o tipo tienen.

Comment: si modificas la pregunta, así sea con valores aleatorios que repitan el mismo error que encuentras podemos ayudarte

Comment: Si y lo agradezco, pero me está quedando complicado poder crear algo parecido así sea con valores aleatorios porque los valores de esta función vienen prácticamente del data cleaning de los datos iniciales. Quizás si lo explico sería más corto.

Comment: De acuerdo con los argumentos que recibe la función (lista de fechas tipo datetime y array numpy de ceros), lo que hace la función upd es convertir este array inicializado en 0 dentro de la función, en un array con algunas posiciones en 1 o 2 y las demás en cero. Y esta distribución de ceros, unos, y doces cambia cada vez que el valor de la lista cambia. La función no retorna nada, pero como le paso como argumento un array externo (density_map), este cambia su valor cada vez que llamo a la función, es eso lo que quiero capturar, todos y cada uno de estos arrays cada vez que llamo a la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a tus comentarios, un código que reproduce el error que tienes es el siguiente:

```
import random
import numpy as np

# Creo una función para modificar aleatoriamente y añadir 1s en cualquier posición
def upd(density_map_inside): 
    h, w = density_map_inside.shape
    for i in range(3):
        i = random.randint(0, w-1)
        j = random.randint(0, h-1)
        density_map_inside[i,j] += 1

density_map = np.zeros((5,5))
im_den = []

for i in range(3):
    upd(density_map)
    im_den.append(density_map)

imagenes = np.array(im_den)
```

Si miras el array de **imagenes** es el mismo array múltiples veces y no guarda la historia de las modificaciones que se han hecho.

```
array([[[0., 2., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 1., 1.]],

       [[0., 2., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 1., 1.]],

       [[0., 2., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 1., 1.]]])
```

De donde viene este error? Para eso hay que entender como python maneja el paso de los argumentos en una función, básicamente es de dos formas.

1. Por valor, se crea una copia local de la variable **dentro de la función**, esto se usa con tipos simples como `int` o `float`
2. Por referencia, se maneja directamente la variable y todos los cambios que se hagan afectan la variable en ese mismo espacio de memoria. Esto se usa para tipos de datos más complejos, como `list`, `dict` o en este caso `np.array`.

Entonces para evitar modificar la misma variable lo que podemos hacer es crear una copia, antes de pasarla a la función y modificar la función para que devuelva este nuevo `density_map` de la siguiente manera.

```
def upd(density_map_inside): 
    h, w = density_map_inside.shape
    for i in range(3):
        i = random.randint(0, w-1)
        j = random.randint(0, h-1)
        density_map_inside[i,j] += 1
    return density_map_inside

density_map = np.zeros((3,3))
im_den = []

for i in range(3):
    im_den.append(upd(density_map.copy()))

imagenes = np.array(im_den)
```

O para que se vea aún mas elegente, podemos usar una comprensión de listas para las últimas lineas donde llamamos la función.

```
imagenes = np.array([ upd(density_map.copy()) for i in range(3)])
```

Y así obtenemos el resultado que esperas donde todos los density_map se guardan en un array.

```
array([[[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1.]],

       [[2., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]],

       [[0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Espero te sirva, y la próxima vez recuerda el **mínimo código viable** hace más facil que se pueda dar un respuesta.

Comment: Diego muchísimas gracias por dedicarme el tiempo, valoro tu colaboración con el mínimo código viable. Gracias por la explicación y la solución, era eso. Yo había probado el hacer una copia con [:], pero claro no había funcionado porque para numpy array era .copy() y pensé que no era ese el inconveniente. Haz sido muy amable y muy oportuno. Hasta pronto.